# Best Practice to handle/document dynamically loaded calls/branches/jumps in IDA

Tags: ida, idapython

I have been reversing some binaries that either have broken relocation tables (ELF binaries), or due to architecture limitations "build" function addresses arithmetically in a register then branch to the register which wrecks havoc in terms of code readability/cross-referencing. Therefore, I wrote an IDApython script to fix up these calls/references. Effectively the script uses poor man's static tracing and some logic to find what function is being called and creates a cross-reference.

`add_cref(ea_from,ea_to,fl_CF)`

In its current state, I create a repeatable comment or a function comment for readability. This works as shown below, and is MUCH better now that I read what a repeatable comment really is, however it can be somewhat annoying keeping function comments synced with function names in the function window and what not while reversing/documenting the binary. Is there a better way of accomplishing this?

Another nuisance is if I re-run auto-analyze, these comments are cleared.

[image: Repeatable Comments/Function Comments]